# PDF Javascript message from PDF to HTML document is not delivered

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I'm trying to get my PDF javascript embedded code to communicate to its HTML container page. But I've been able to make it work only 1 way(HTML->PDF)

Maybe the problem is that the object tag is being generated dynamically( because I need to load pdfs on-the-fly)

js in my pdf file(runs in the OPEN action):

```
this.hostContainer.messageHandler =
{
 onMessage: function(messageArray)
 {
   app.alert('msg received' + messageArray);
 },
 onError: function(error, messageArray){ },
 onDisclose: function() {return true;}
};

try{
  this.hostContainer.postMessage(["never", "delivered"]);  // this line doesn't work. :(
}
  catch(e){
  app.alert(e.message);
}
```

my html page js code :

```
function messageFunc(messageArray) {
    alert('finally!!');
}


 $j('#pdf_div').html("<object type='application/pdf' data='http://url.to.dinamically.generated.pdf' id='PdfObject'> </object>");


  $j("#PdfObject").ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('PdfObject').messageHandler = { onMessage: messageFunc };
  });
```

As I said, the PDF can receive the messages without problems, but I'm unable to send messages from the PDF to HTML code.

Btw, I'm using JQuery.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.